# Jenkins WebHook URL for a particular folder in a branch

Tags: jenkins

I am using GitHub form our code management, we are having a branch say X in that we a re having multiple folders for each month release and future month release, for example for august month release we will be RB-2018.08.01.x and for September we will have RB-2018.09.01.x like wise.. So each one will be working on each folder.
I created a web hook URL which triggers a Job in Jenkins, so now issue is like whomever is committing code in any of the branch WEB HOOK is getting triggered.
I want to create a web hook URL for each folder which triggers particular Job at Jenkins.
So i am looking for when one commits in August code it should trigger corresponding August URL.
Really appreciate if some one can help me, looking for solution from long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhook triggers work at the repository level and NOT branch level. Any commit in the repo irrespective of the branch the webhook is triggered.

To be able to control webhook behavior I’d recommend you look at using Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin which lets you extract specific values from the webhook like branch, commit message, files changed etc and then use those values to either trigger a downstream pipeline or just do nothing i.e. ignore the webhook. Lot of flexibility in choosing this option.

We use this option and it works perfectly!

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.. How can we get Branch name from webhook URL

Comment: Hi, see https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin and install this plugin. Since you are using GitHub for SCM, when you commit a change a webhook is triggered, sample webhook payload from GitHub looks like this - https://gist.github.com/gjtorikian/5171861. For branch name as you can see from the sample payload you can use `$.ref` to see which branch the repo has triggered from and build/ ignore depending on the branch name. Hope this helps!